# normalize-space just works with xpath not css selector

Tags: python, css, python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

i am extracting data using scrapy and python.

the data sometimes include spaces. i was using `normalize-space` with xpath to remove those spaces like this:

```
xpath('normalize-space(.//li[2]/strong/text())').extract()
```

It words very good. However, now i want to use `normalize-space` with css selector.

I tried this:

```
car['Location'] = site.css('normalize-space(div[class=location]::text)').extract()
```

I got empty result though i get correct result if i removed the normalize-space..

please how to use it with css selector?

#### i tried

```
def normalize_whitespace(str):
        import re
        str = str.strip()
        str = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', str)
        return str
```

and i called this fucntion like this:

```
car['Location'] = normalize_whitespace(site.css('div[class=location]::text').extract())
```

but i got empty result. why please?

Comment: `.extract()` returns a list of unicode strings. and this `normalize_whitespace` takes a unicode string as input. So you need either to use `.extract()[0]` (if you know you expect only 1 string result in the list), or you can serialize the unicode string list with `u''.join(site.css('div[class=location]::text').extract())`

Comment: @pault. it is just one string result. but i got empty reslut, please check my code

Comment: did you add `[0]` after `.extract()`?

Comment: @pault. what am i doing wrong in my code so i got emplty result. also as i told you. if i removed the call of that function i got the whole data

Comment: @pault. yes. exactly as you did in your answer

Comment: define `normalize_whitespace` outside your spider class

Comment: are you the genius ? I think so :) :) you the one man, thanks a lot. also, i have another thing about encoding, i asked you about it yesterday. todya i will ask it again. please if you have time answer it. i appreciate you help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, XPath functions are not available with CSS selectors in Scrapy.

You could first translate your `div[class=location]::text` CSS selector to the equivalent XPath expression and then wrap it in `normalize-space()` as input to `.xpath()`.

Anyhow, as you are only interested in a final "whitespace-normalized" string, you could achieve the same with a Python function on the output of the CSS selector extract.

See for example http://snipplr.com/view/50410/normalize-whitespace/ :

```
def normalize_whitespace(str):
    import re
    str = str.strip()
    str = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', str)
    return str
```

If you include this function somewhere in your Scrapy project, you could use it like this:

```
    car['Location'] = normalize_whitespace(
        u''.join(site.css('div[class=location]::text').extract()))
```

or

```
    car['Location'] = normalize_whitespace(
        site.css('div[class=location]::text').extract()[0])
```

Comment: I like that page you state, please how can i use that function in my situation ? also, i always thank you. you always help me with python and scrapy. +1

Comment: You're welcome, that's what StackOverflow is about. I added an example of how to use the Python function to normalize whitespace with the output of your CSS selector `.extract()` result

Comment: I also tried your edited solution but get an emplty result. maybe i added the function wrong?

Comment: i tried you solution but get an emplty result, please check all my code in the question. the code works good if i removed the call of the whitespace fuction, but returns empty result when add that function

Answer (score 2):

css() compiles an xpath, so you can chain it to a xpath() normalising the spaces, so change your code to:

```
car['Location'] = site.css('normalize-space(div[class=location])').xpath('normalize-space(text())').extract()
```