# Scrape categories and its urls from alibaba and put it in two column

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy, css-selectors

Hi I am new to scrapy and I am trying to **scrape** categories and URLs of categories from alibaba's [Product By categories](https://www.alibaba.com/Products?spm=a2700.8293689.scGlobalHomeHeader.352.2ce265aa7GOmOF) page. I am trying to scrape it and put it on a CSV file.

Here is the view I want to give when I open it in a spreadsheet is:-

```
categories                           categories_urls

Agricultural Growing Media           its URL
Animal Products                      its URL
.                                    .
.                                    .
.                                    .
```

### Code:-

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

class AlibabaCatagoriesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'alibaba_catagories'
allowed_domains = ['alibaba.com']
start_urls = ['https://www.alibaba.com/Products?spm=a2700.8293689.scGlobalHomeHeader.352.2ce265aa7GOmOF']

def parse(self, response):
    a = response.css('ul.sub-item-cont')
    for catag in a:
        item = {
           'categories': catag.css('li>a::text').extract(),
           'categories_url': catag.css('li>a::attr(href)').extract()
            }
        yield item
```

### Problems

- \n and white space are scraped while scraping categories.
- The data is not scraped in a desirable format

### How can you help

- Modify the code so we can have the
- Give the trick to remove \n and white space while scraping

desirable format.

Comment: What do you mean by "desirable format"?

Comment: I want to  have the name of categories in one page and their URLs at another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty easy with Scrapy:

```
def parse(self, response):

    for category_node in response.xpath('//ul[contains(@class, "sub-item-cont")]/li/a'):

        item = {
           'categories': category_node.xpath('./text()').extract_first().strip(),
           'categories_url': category_node.xpath('./@href').extract_first()
        }
        yield item
```

Comment: Hi, sir I am trying to implement the same thing please see this -->  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52235721/scrape-products-from-scrapy-and-follow-pagination?noredirect=1#comment91419945_52235721)

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def parser():
    url = 'https://www.alibaba.com/Products?spm=a2700.8293689.scGlobalHomeHeader.352.2ce265aa7GOmOF'
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
    name_dict = {}
    for l in soup.find_all('li'):
        content = l.find('a')
        if content:
            href = content.get('href')
            name = content.get_text()
            if href.find('_pid') != -1:
            name_dict[name] = href
    return name_dict
```

This is been made by BeautifulSoup module as it is easier to scrape with it. The function will return a dictionary with key as name and value as url.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use normalize-space function to remove the spaces. It is not available or very complicated with `.css` selectors. I recommend you to use `XPath`. 
As described here.
[normalize-space just works with xpath not css selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21118582/normalize-space-just-works-with-xpath-not-css-selector)

Example of Xpath using normalize-space function

```
 Product=   response.xpath('normalize-space(//*[@class="column one3"]/a/@href)').extract()
```

Answer (score 0):

try following selector

```
list(map(lambda x: x.replace('\n', '').strip(), response.xpath('//*[@class="cg-main"]//*[contains(@class, "sub-item-cont")]//li/a[@href]/text()').extract()))
```