# Scrape Products from scrapy and follow pagination

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to scrape data using scrapy from [Alibaba](https://www.alibaba.com/catalog/agricultural-growing-media_cid144?spm=a2700.galleryofferlist.galleryFilter.10.75151bbaRWCfhu) [Agriculture and Growing Media Category](https://www.alibaba.com/catalog/agricultural-growing-media_cid144?spm=a2700.galleryofferlist.galleryFilter.10.75151bbaRWCfhu). You can [Click Here](https://www.alibaba.com/catalog/agricultural-growing-media_cid144?spm=a2700.galleryofferlist.galleryFilter.10.75151bbaRWCfhu) to see view the page.

The data I want to scrape from the page are ***Product_name, Price, Min_order, Company Name, Url of image***.

**The picture shows what I want to scrape**
[image]

### My Python code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class AlibabaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'alibaba'
    allowed_domains = ['alibaba.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.alibaba.com/catalog/agricultural-growing-media_cid144?spm=a2700.9161164.1.2.4a934e02VlSXiW']

def parse(self, response):
    for products in response.xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "m-gallery-product-item-wrap")]/div/div'):
        item = {
            'product_name': products.xpath('.//h2/a/@title').extract_first(),
            'price':  products.xpath('(.//div[@class="price"]/b/text())').extract_first().strip(),
            'min_order': products.xpath('.//div[@class="min-order"]/b/text()').extract_first(),
            'company_name': products.xpath('.//div[@class="stitle util-ellipsis"]/a/@title').extract_first(),
            'prod_detail_link': products.xpath('.//div[@class="item-img-inner"]/a/@href').extract_first()
            #'response_rate': products.xpath('.//i[@class="ui2-icon ui2-icon-skip"]/text()').extract_first(),
            #'image_url': products.xpath('.//div[@class=""]/').extract_first(),
         }
        yield item
```

### Problems

- This code scraped only 21 out of 36 item from the page
- How to follow the pagination link?

### How can you help

- Modify the code so that all the data is scraped from the page.
- Modify the code to follow the pagination and keep scraping.

Comment: Try to just put dot in the beginning of each XPath, e.g. `.//h2/a/@title`. It will point to context (`products`)

Comment: @Andersson That seems to work but it only scrapes half of the data (only 21 out of 36) and what about pagination?

Comment: Use one more (outer) `for` loop to iterate over pages. Try URL `"https://www.alibaba.com/catalog/agricultural-growing-media_cid144?spm=a2700.9161164.1.2.4a934e02VlSXiW&page=%s" % i` where `i` is page number (starting from `1`)